# How the Protocol http or https is determined when we enter the website name?

Tags: http, https

Can anyone Explain me how the protocol (http or https) is determined when we enter website name ?

DNS gives the information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a web browser, if you specify no protocol then the protocol is http and port 80. If the site is configured correctly and the resource should be encrypted, the server will send a https redirect to port 443 in reply from that unencrypted request.

Comment: Here the site configuration means , server  side configurations ? From where it is getting the onformation ?

Comment: @user3103694 It can be done through code as well. For example, you can check the request protocol with everything from asp to php and jsp or with apache rewrite rules. So, this information is wherever the site administrator and developers put it.